# How do I list, map and "print if count>0" with Java 8 / stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Here's my code as per now.

```
List<Cat> cats = petStore.getCatsForSale();

if (!cats.empty) 
    logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size());

for (Cat cat : cats) {
    cat.giveFood();
}
```

My colleague writes realy nice code using the Java stream API. I tried to rewrite it as one streaming statement, but I got stuck.

```
petStore.getCatsForSale().stream.forEach(cat -> cat.giveFood)
    .countTheCats().thenDo(logger.info("Total number of cats: " + x)); // Incorrect... is this possible?
```

How can I do this? Ideally I want a single streaming statement...

Comment: What is `count`?  Do you expect a log statement for every non empty cat?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure *why* you want to use streams as the current loop solutions works, but you may as well use a `Stream<List<Cat>>`:

```
Stream.of(petStore.getCatsForSale())
    .filter(cats -> !cats.isEmpty())
    .flatMap(cats -> {
        logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size());
        return cats.stream();
    })
    .forEach(Cat::giveFood);
```

Maybe an optimization:

```
Stream.of(petStore.getCatsForSale())
    .filter(cats -> !cats.isEmpty())
    .peek(cats -> logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size()))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .forEach(Cat::giveFood);
```

Or use this other variant:

```
Stream.of(petStore.getCatsForSale())
    .filter(cats -> !cats.isEmpty())
    .mapToInt(cats -> {
        cats.forEach(Cat::giveFood);
        return cats.size();
    })
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(count -> logger.info("Processing for cats: " + count));
```

Comment: `petStore.getCatsForSale()` is a `List<Cat>`

Comment: @nullpointer I know and with this ugly piece of code consisting of Java8 streams I think it works, correct me if I'm wrong of course :)

Comment: @CommonMan not really, its empty vs non-empty here. I doubt `Optional` would be useful here much.

Comment: Thank you sir! Works :) Is there a way to improve the contents of the "flatMap", so it's one line instead of two? I notice it returns "cats.stream()" there, is that necessary?

Comment: An opinion based tempted No to the latter solution. I feel like its getting clumsy with the stream approach. (Didn't really downvote though.)

Comment: @vikingsteve see the second variant

Comment: @vikingsteve Actually, there's **one line solution**.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't really like any of the solutions here except the one from you, I think using Streams for everyday logic is just overkill and makes it extremly hard to understand the simplest of logic

Comment: Having side-effects in non-terminal operations is very ugly. @nullpointer's solution is way much cleaner.

Comment: Why did you use Stream.of(cats) instead of cats.stream ?

Comment: and maybe an `Optional` version with Java-11 syntax could be `Optional.of(cats)
                .filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))
                .stream()
                .peek(cat -> logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size()))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .forEach(Cat::giveFood);`

Comment: @Spara so that I have a "wrapper"-stream around the `Cat`-list (`Stream<List<Cat>>`) which allows me to operate on the whole list at once, but still inside the stream. Using `cats.stream()` though will give you a stream over all cats (`Stream<Cat>`)

Comment: @nullpointer I like your oneliner there, thank you. It works too :)

Answer (score 18):

Your current code is much better without a stream and can further be cutshort to:

```
if (!cats.isEmpty()) {
    logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size());
}
cats.forEach(Cat::giveFood); // Assuming giveFood is a stateless operation
```

Comment: Hi and thx for answer. Can this be done in a one liner? Of course I can write `"if (!cats.isEmpty()) logger.info("...")` but the purpose of this question is to write it with streams

Comment: In my opinion, is this the only acceptable solution. *Don't* do everything with `Stream`s just because a tutorial told you so, just by looking at every answer here it's clear what the intentions of **this** one here is, but for every other? It's just a mess

Answer (score 4):

```
cats.stream()
    .peek(Cat::giveFood)
    .findAny().ifPresent(cat -> logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size()));
```

Comment: Starting from `java-9` you may leave your cats **hungry** ))). Execution of `peek` is not guaranteed anymore. Please read [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) for more details.

Comment: @ETO Please look at tags. It says **java-8**!

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I think ETO wanted to say that this solution may only work for java-8 which makes it not a favorable solution when one wants to migrate the version upwards :)

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Yes, I know. Using `peek` for non-debugging purposes is considered harmful anyway.

Comment: Moreover, starting from February 2019 there is [no long-term support](https://java.com/en/download/release_notice.jsp) of `java-8` for cemmercial users. So if you write `java-8` code, consider avoiding potential migration bugs. One may not notice that `java-9`'s `peek` is not working as it did before. Thus your code will have a hidden unobvious bug.

Comment: Execution of `peek()` is not guaranteed in Java 8, either.  Certainly not when followed by `findAny()`, which is a short-circuiting operation.  I wrote this code in Java 8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880849/507761

Comment: Stop spamming. I know all these changes from JVM9. This example works under JVM8

Comment: This does _not_ work in Java 8.  Run this and count the "meow"s: http://tpcg.io/VWHXlA

Answer (score 2):

I agree [with @Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530220/how-do-i-list-map-and-print-if-count0-with-java-8-stream-api/54530431#54530431). This is another alternative based on his idea:

```
List<Cat> cats = petStore.getCatsForSale();

cats.stream().limit(1)
    .flatMap(c -> {
        logger.info("Processing for cats: " + cats.size());
        return cats.stream();
    }).forEach(Cat::giveFood);
```

Comment: Why not use an `IntStream.range(1)`? No need to use `cats.stream().limit(1)` that way

Comment: @Lino because of empty list